# mysql inner join on multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, select, join

Trying to do an inner join on two composite tables, having trouble with the syntax. Here's what I have:

`SELECT
count(*)
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT seller FROM Items, Users WHERE Items.seller = Users.userID t1
   INNER JOIN
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM Bids, Users WHERE Bids.UserID = Users.userID
   )
   t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID
)`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the parantheses/lack of as/or whatever. I guess what I'm really asking here is how to give my subqueries aliases, but not using as in the FROM part. Is it valid just to have t1 after User.userID and identify that whole table as t1?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Items ON Users.userID = Items.seller
INNER JOIN Bids ON Users.UserID = Bids.UserID
```

Comment: no, that's not specific enough I guess. I need to keep the same structure of the two seperate tables because I know they're right, I just need help on fixing the syntax

Comment: @MichaelLiao `t1` does not have UserID but seller, maybe `ON t1.seller= t2.userID`

Comment: @MichaelLiao And you just want to count the records, what do you mean of keep the same structure??

Comment: The tables the way I described them are the ones that I want, I just want to know how to perform an inner join between them

Comment: I figured out the problem, this was actually the wrong approach. It was actually easier to do the problem using a relationship between a different table not mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to name the output table which you get from query

```
SELECT DISTINCT seller FROM Items, Users WHERE Items.seller = Users.userID
```

as t1 
simple way is use

```
`select * from (SELECT DISTINCT seller FROM Items, Users WHERE Items.seller = Users.userID)t1`
```